# Query about the spark from the movie Avatharam

Tags: spacex, comet, meteoroid

The Telugu movie Avatharam, depicts an object resembling a meteor or comet with an interesting tail seen [here from 24:49 to 30:00](https://youtube.com/watch?&v=6sjQGHq10Qo&t=1489).

[image]

Have we encountered (or there a theoretical basis for believing that we might encounter) anything that resembles this in space?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network - sci-fi and fantasy.

Comment: @phil1008 we vote to close questions *when they are off-topic here*, not because we think they belong somewhere else. ["I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Physics SE" is bad and here's why](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2866/12102) Sometimes a question is on topic in multiple sites, sometimes it's not on topic in any site, so "close because belongs on" isn't a workable criteria.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about actual Space Exploration (and because with the information available it's likely to be answerable only with opinions).

Comment: @uhoh Thanks for the feedback. I've decided retracting my close vote because the question is fixable.

Comment: @phil1008 I question your edit; it's not clear which features of the object the OP was interested in. OP should clarify that, not someone else, lest that someone change the question into a different one.

Comment: @uhoh I won't fight to try to keep this one open or anything, but I answered the question by reading it as "what is the term for this thing, assuming you saw something like it," which seemed sort-of on-topic here and maybe more on-topic on Astronomy SE instead. It seemed more meteor-y than comet-y in the couple of seconds I watched, aside from it having a voiceover. I'm not 100% that was OP's intent, but assuming it was, do you think that question would be on topic? Or still no?

Comment: @ErinAnne if it's "identify this natural phenomenon" but not "how can this thing be explored", I'd say it's off-topic here, and after closing, *potentially* on-topic for migration in Astronomy. However, if it's "what was this thing I saw in a SciFi movie?" it's again off-topic here, and after closing, *potentially* on-topic for migration in SciFi SE (or Movies SE though not likely well-received there by that particular community).

Comment: @phil1008 ditto.

Comment: I don't think a "how realistic is this sci-fi movie effect" question fits well on Astronomy.SE. We occasionally get such questions on Physics.SE, but they tend to get a mixed reaction.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't manage to provide the link. Presumably you're talking about this:
[image: still capture from Avatharam on Youtube, showing what appears to be a meteor entering Earth's atmosphere]

This is somewhat like a [meteor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteoroid#Meteors), though the depiction is....weird. I'm not going to spend a lot of time watching the film to try to understand what is correct about the depiction.

Comment: uhoh's arguments above convinced me the question was off-topic. My answer got a couple upvotes so...I don't know. I'll leave it unless people think it should be deleted. Even if I delete it I think that just hides it from people below a certain rep threshold; I know I see deleted stuff all over.